# .htaccess redirect old file name to new name (same file)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Currently, this is my .htaccess setup

```
RewriteRule ^buy-things-online plans5.php [NC,L]
```

Which works well when users go to https://example.com/buy-things-online they are really seeing plans5.php and the page URL say https://example.com/buy-things-online

My issue is when users visit the real page https://example.com/plans5.php they are not redirected to the new name for that page (same file)

I tried using 301 redirects 
Which just resulted in a loop since it is the same file and the browser said "too many redirects"

Comment: Please post the code you tried to redirect the url.

Comment: Redirect 301 /plans5.php https://example.com/buy-things-online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# important to use THE_REQUEST that doesn't change after other rules
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /plans5\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /buy-things-online [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^buy-things-online plans5.php [NC,L]
```